# How to join same table more than once

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am using postgresql.

I have a table called custom_field_answers. The data looks like this.

```
Id | product_id | value      | number_value | 
4  | 2          |            | 117          |
3  | 1          |            | 107          |
2  | 1          | bangle     |              |
1  | 2          | necklace   |              |
```

I want to find all the products which has text_value as 'bangle' and number_value less than 50.

```
SELECT p.*
FROM "products" AS p
INNER JOIN "custom_field_answers" AS a1 ON p."id" = a1."product_id"
INNER JOIN "custom_field_answers" AS a2 ON p."id" = a1."product_id" 
WHERE a1."value" = 'bangle' AND a2."number_value" < 50
```

I tried to produce that sql with following code.

```
conditions = <conditions from arel>
relation = self.scoped
conditions.each do |condition|
  relation = relation.merge(where(condition))
end
joins(:custom_field_answers).merge(relation)
relation.to_a
```

This produces following sql

```
SELECT "products".* FROM "products" INNER JOIN "custom_field_answers" 
ON "custom_field_answers"."product_id" = "products"."id" 
WHERE ("custom_field_answers"."value" ILIKE 'bangle') 
AND ("custom_field_answers"."number_value" < 50)
```

As you can see this sql is not similar to the desired sql(mentioned at the top).

I tried moving the joins code up a little like this

```
relation = self.scoped
conditions.each do |condition|
  relation = relation.merge(where(condition).joins(:custom_field_answers))
end
relation.to_a
```

Still no luck.

Anyone knows how to force a new join for each relation. I am using Rails 3.1.1 .

Comment: I do not understand why you join `custom_field_answers` to `products` twice

Answer (score 7):

Your best bet for 'non standard' queries such as these would be to go down straight to [Arel](https://github.com/rails/arel).

Something like this should work:

```
# in your model
p  = Arel::Table.new(:products, :as => 'p')
a1 = Arel::Table.new(:custom_field_answers, :as => 'a1')
a2 = Arel::Table.new(:custom_field_answers, :as => 'a2')

relation = p.
  project(Arel.sql('*')).
  join(a1).on(p[:id].eq(a1[:product_id])).
  join(a2).on(p[:id].eq(a2[:product_id]))

relation = relation.where(a1[:value].eq('bangle')).where(a2[:number_value].lt(50))

relation.to_sql #should return the SQL you're after
```

Not as nice as the Rails Arel Wrapper, but for complex queries it's the only way if you don't wanna drop to raw SQL in your code.

Does this help?

Answer (score -1):

```
 Select * from products where product_id 
 IN 
 (Select product_id  from custom_answers 
  where 
  text_value = 'bangle' 
  AND number_value<50)
```