# How to join on the same table multiple times?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I'm querying for the mutual friends of a given two users. The query below should do the trick for the most part and the friendship table should be self-evident, containing a `user_id` and `friend_id`.

```
SELECT `users`.* FROM `users`
INNER JOIN `friendships` `a` ON `users`.`id` = `a`.`friend_id`
INNER JOIN `friendships` `b` ON `users`.`id` = `b`.`friend_id`
WHERE `a`.`user_id` = 1 AND `b`.`user_id` = 2
```

What's got me confused is how to write this semantic `ActiveRecord`. With ActiveRecord you can join on an association, but only once. So how do you go about writing this as plainly as possible in `ActiveRecord`?

Comment: You can also see how to use Arel to achieve this goal in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8237151/3676469)

Answer (score 20):

I do it with string arguments to `joins`:

```
User.
  joins("INNER JOIN friendships a ON users.id = a.friend_id").
  joins("INNER JOIN friendships b ON users.id = b.friend_id").
  where("a.user_id" => 1, "b.user_id" => 2)
```

I'm not aware of a higher-level way to do such a join with Active Record.

Comment: It's perhaps also worth mentioning that joining twice means that "a" and "b" can actually be the same record, unless you've got a condition that rules this out. The condition above rules it out (because it specifies different IDs for both). A condition like `where("a.id != b.id")` would also rule it out.

Comment: Awesome thank you! I spent a lot of time on this and was resorting to INTERSECT and find_by_sql. This is so much better and also scale well to more than 2 joins

Comment: Super useful for joining a table with itself!

Answer (score -3):

Firstly, you should have proper **Model Relationship** between **User** & **Friendship**.

```
user model:
 has_many :friendships

friendship model:
 belongs_to :user
```

with that:
you can **get** activerecords in your iteration like:

```
users = User.all
users.each do |user|
 user.friendships
 .....
end
```

Or, by specific user, like:

```
user = User.first
user.friendships #returns association

or 

User.first.friendships
```

for **2 specific users (given)**, you can do like:

```
User.where(id: [1,2]) #array of user id, then get the friendship record as above.
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Nope. Sorry, this doesn't answer my question and wasn't helpful.